# PayPal id_token verification

Tags: paypal, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

I'm implementing "Log In with PayPal" functionality. Should be fairly simple, but unfortunately PayPal lacks documentation (only some basic things are described).

I get authorization_code using "Log In with PayPal" widget. Than I make a request to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice and get JSON with access_token, refresh_token and id_token. I want to get unique user identifier, so I decode id_token, but I'm not able to verify signature of my id_token. Id_token header contains `{"alg": "HS256", "typ": "JWT"}`.

What secret should I use? Tried my app's secret (same that I use to access tokenservice), but it didn't work (using https://jwt.io/ debugger).

Comment: Don't they offer a discovery document ? [http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html ]

Comment: @KcDoD maybe they have, but it doesn't seem to be documented :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal is not OpenID connect compliant. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143353/using-login-with-paypal-and-using-openid-with-aws-cognito) answer explains the reasons.

PayPal expose a configuration endpoint - https://www.paypalobjects.com/.well-known/openid-configuration.It only support `HS256` and does not support or mention about `RS256`. This could be due to a proprietary validation for ID token. For example a id token used as a bearer token.

Alternative solution would be to invoke `userinfo` endpoint as described by [document](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/). This endpoint can be invoked using `access token` and document says it would return the `user_id`

> **user_id** - identifier for the end-user at the issuer.

*Although it seems that `user_id` found in the userinfo is different from `sub` that could be extracted from id_token.*

**How to find public keys if signing algorithm is RS256**

ID token is a JWT. As you have found out, it contains a JWS signature which acts as a MAC.

This signature is a signed using a private key. The receiver of the id token can validate the token using the public key. To find the public key, openid conenct specify a discovery document. You can read more about this from the [specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html)

In the discovery document, you get a special endpoint to infer the configuration `.well-known/openid-configuration`. And one of the must have metadata of the configuration response is `jwk_url`

**jwks_uri**

> REQUIRED. URL of the OP's JSON Web Key Set [JWK] document. This
>   contains the signing key(s) the RP uses to validate signatures from
>   the OP. The JWK Set MAY also contain the Server's encryption key(s),
>   which are used by RPs to encrypt requests to the Server. When both
>   signing and encryption keys are made available, a use (Key Use)
>   parameter value is REQUIRED for all keys in the referenced JWK Set to
>   indicate each key's intended usage. Although some algorithms allow the
>   same key to be used for both signatures and encryption, doing so is
>   NOT RECOMMENDED, as it is less secure. The JWK x5c parameter MAY be
>   used to provide X.509 representations of keys provided. When used, the
>   bare key values MUST still be present and MUST match those in the
>   certificate.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Isn't the case you described for RSA signature? Mine have HS256 (this is described in JOSE). So it should be a simple case where both client & server sign using one shared key. Isn't it so?

Comment: @Fedor ahh, yes. I didn't put attention to the algorithm in the jose header.  Well I came over this dev discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mod_auth_openidc/fPc_C8rb9ns

Comment: well, here comes a good explanation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143353/using-login-with-paypal-and-using-openid-with-aws-cognito. I hope this should clear doubts :)

Comment: thanks a lot for you effort. unfortunately in the question you mentioned there is no solution for how to verify id_token. For now I'll probably go with alternative solution requesting ```userinfo```, but hopefully someone from @paypal can help with this, as it looks total mystery